# How do I do multiple unions with select as on codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I am trying to convert this following code into php codeigniter query but i seem to fail.

This SQL works perfectly:

```
SELECT item_stocks_1 as item_stocks_1 FROM orders WHERE item_id_1 = 7 AND delivery_date = '2019-03-24'
UNION
SELECT item_stocks_2 as item_stocks_2 FROM orders WHERE item_id_2 = 7 AND delivery_date = '2019-03-24'
UNION
SELECT item_stocks_3 as item_stocks_3 FROM orders WHERE item_id_3 = 7 AND delivery_date = '2019-03-24'
UNION
SELECT item_stocks_4 as item_stocks_4 FROM orders WHERE item_id_4 = 7 AND delivery_date = '2019-03-24'
UNION
SELECT item_stocks_5 as item_stocks_5 FROM orders WHERE item_id_5 = 7 AND delivery_date = '2019-03-24'
```

but when I convert it into codeigniter query like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<$5;$i++){
$this->db->select('item_stocks_'.$i as 'item_stocks_'.$i);
$this->db->from('orders');
$this->db->where('item_id_', $filtered_item_id);
$this->db->where('delivery_date', '2019-03-24');
UNION
}
```

it always fails. i have tried searching for unions on codeigniter but they only unite 2 tables.

This is how my table looks like:

```
delivery_date  |   item_id_1   |   item_stocks_1  |  item_id_2   |   item_stocks_2  | item_id_3   |   item_stocks_3  | item_id_4   |   item_stocks_4  | item_id_5   |   item_stocks_5  |
```

Comment: where is the statement `$this->db->get()`?

Comment: i dont know how to use union :)

Answer (score 0):

use group start for .

```
$this->db->select('item_stocks_'.$i as 'item_stocks_'.$i);
$this->db->from('orders');
for($i=1;$i<$5;$i++){
$this->db->or_group_start();
$this->db->where('item_id_', $filtered_item_id);
$this->db->where('delivery_date', '2019-03-24')->group_end();
}
$this->db->get();
```

Comment: Here `$i` is outside the for loop.

Comment: why is it outside? how can it tell the count?